# Define a rootpath in php

Tags: php, document-root

I read up on how to define a rootpath constant that is useable in all subpages when using a single page application.

Now my question is, how can i use the basepath in my scripts i point to in my form actions?

My problem is that i want to use a relative path, compared to where the script is located, in the "action" scripts so that the path will work no matter from where that file is called.

I tried using

```
dirname(__FILE__)
```

but as i use files in parent directories some levels up i ended up with something like

```
dirname(dirname((__FILE__))
```

and sometimes even another level up and i did not like the look of that.

After trying to to use a basepath constant i found out that it is not accessable in the scripts my forms are calling on form submit.

So my question is. How can i use a common basepath that works in the entire application? I was thinking about storing it in a session, but that seemed like a bad idea as it has no real place there.

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using a particular framework at all? as most frameworks would specify a basepath in boostrap or dispatch file of sorts...

Comment: you can base all of your urls off of `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]`

Comment: In >PHP5.3 ``dirname(__DIR__) = dirname(dirname(__FILE__)``

Comment: @Fibbe you mean `__DIR__`

Comment: @InGodITrust ``__DIR__ = dirname(__FILE__)``

Comment: So the best practice is to nest dirname() until you are at the appropiate level or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no common basepath for both the client- and the server-side of your application.

On the client side, all paths are relative to the current url or absolute which is relative to the base url / domain name.

On the server side your are dealing with the file-system.

So if your site root on the server-side (`$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]`) is something like `/home/some-user/www` and your form processor is located at `/home/some-user/www/assets/inc/process-form-1.php`, that is the exact path you need on the server-side (if you want to use absolute paths...).

However, on the client-side, your `action` would point to a relative path or an absolute path which in this case would be `/assets/inc/process-form-1.php`; an absolute path relative to the root of the web-server.

Comment: That is some good information.

But is it possible to have a variable that is accessable by the form processing script without having to include the script in every processing script?

Comment: @Rasmus I'm not sure I understand what you are looking for, does `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` not give you all you need?

Answer (score 0):

The most usual solution is

```
dirname(dirname(__FILE__))
```

It is the most reliable solution, dont forget you can always go backwards as well

```
dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/../'
```

Comment: @TimothyGroote which was exactly the reason why I wanted to set him right. Helping a person sometimes means telling him what is the best thing to do, not what he thinks is best!