# PHP Security for Directories

Tags: php, security

I am wondering if my approach is both secure and a good way to implement file referencing.  I understand that you can use:

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "includes/config.php"
```

to reference files within a PHP script.  However, I assumed that it would be a security vulnerability if I used that same call in a manor such as this:

```
<img src="<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ?>/images/image.jpg" />
```

Since my base file directory will be visible to the frontend users.  In order to fix this, I ended up adding a command to my config.php file (executed on every page) that does this:

```
chdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
```

This way I always know that I need to reference from the root and the frontend user will not be able to see my file structure.  Is this a good method?

Comment: You are missing something fundamental here, check out my answer to this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574224/define-a-rootpath-in-php/17574607#17574607

Comment: I apologize but I don't understand your response to the other post.  I implemented these changes and it works for both images on the client side and for including files in PHP.  Are you implying that there is a security concern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I assumed that it would be a security vulnerability if I used that same call in a manor such as this:

```
<img src="<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ?>/images/image.jpg" />
```

It's not a security vulnerability(*), it just won't work. `<img src>` is an external URL address accessed by the client; `DOCUMENT_ROOT` is an internal file address used by server scripts.

The document root is the filesystem path which corresponds to the external root url (`/`). So if your document root was `/home/me/www-data`, then the image given to the browser above would be `src="/home/me/www-data/images/image.jpg"`, the browser would ask the server for the URL `/home/me/www-data/images/image.jpg`, and the server would look for that file *inside the document root*: `/home/me/www-data/home/me/www-data/images/image.jpg`. Since presumably that filepath doesn't exist, the server replies with a `404` and you get a broken image.

(*: well... unless your document root directory happens to have HTML-special characters like `<` in, which is unlikely. Still, you always `htmlspecialchars()` any variable value you are dropping into an HTML page, to avoid HTML-injection issues.)

> chdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);

This does nothing. The web server serves up images relative to the document root by itself—none of your PHP scripts will be run for an image request.